# Reference a ParentRequests constructor parameters inside IProvider

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Is there a way to reference a parent's constructor arguments from within `kernel.Bind<>().ToMethod()` (effectively an `IProvider`)?

I'm have a scenario like:

```
public class Bar{
   public Bar(ILogger logger) {}
}

public class Foo{
   public Foo(ILogger logger, Bar bar){}
}
```

and let's say I have some loggers:

```
public class TopLevelLogger{
}

public class ChildLogger{
   public ChildLogger(ILogger parent){}
}
```

When I setup my binding, I need to get a reference to the parent class's logger:

```
kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ILogger>.ToMethod(ctx => 
{
   if (null == ctx.Request.ParentRequest.ParentRequest) 
      // at top level (ie Foo)
      return new TopLevelLogger();

   // I know I've already created a TopLevelLogger, how do I get access to it?
  var parentLogger = ???????
  return new ChildLogger(parentLogger);
});
```

Comment: How long shall the parent logger live? You might want to look into scoping.

Comment: How do you mean by scoping?

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes - in your case it might also be a custom scope.